# Server api not responding to Curl function

Tags: php, c++, curl, apache2

### Appendix

I have a service API on mine server which is reachable at 213.209.253.6:7209.
I need to contact the API from a website(php) on a server hosted by 3rd(Aruba) and from my internal network via c++ program.

### ENV

#### Situation 1 (development)

Website still in dev phase so running xampp in localhost and request to the API via external ip or internal network ip, fine working and also the c++ code have no problem. Requests via browser and curl console ever worked;

#### Situation 2 (production)

Website live with domain on 3rd party server. The requests fails for mixed content (website in https and API in http) pretty reasonable. To solve this i modified the httpd.conf file of the server API loading the ssl_moudle, configuring the certificate .key,.crt and ca-bundle and listening on 7210 for secure requests.

#### Situation 3 (SSL production)

API responding fine to(both secure and unsecure connections): browser, curl console, javascript(ajax) code of live website, php and javascript code of website**(only from localhost)**
API not responding to live production website from curl php code and from curl c++ code in program running in local network;

### OUTPUT

for php
The "not responding" means that the request stay unanswered till the connection close byitself or i close it with timeout no data exchanged no other info from curl_getinfo() or curl_error() (also in VERBOSE mode). No apache log on the API server. 
for c++
Also here the "not responding" means that the request stay unanswered till the connection close but apache logs it with:

(access_log)

```
192.168.1.113 - - [06/Apr/2019:11:40:33 +0200] "GET HTTP://192.168.1.130:7209/ HTTP/1.1" 400 226
```

(error_log)

```
[Sat Apr 06 11:01:23.937408 2019] [core:debug] [pid 12567:tid 3000998720] vhost.c(1169): [client 192.168.1.113:59008] AH02417: Replacing host header '192.168.1.130:7209' with host '192.168.1.130:7209' given in the request uri
[Sat Apr 06 11:01:23.937915 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12567:tid 3000998720] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.1.113:59008] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Sat Apr 06 11:01:23.937936 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 12567:tid 3000998720] mod_authz_core.c(820): [client 192.168.1.113:59008] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Sat Apr 06 11:01:44.196715 2019] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 12567:tid 3000998720] [client 192.168.1.113:59008] AH01382: Request body read timeout
```

### SNIPPETs

I'm struggling into this since 2 days...

here only code of c++, the php code is about the same with different syntax but same result...

```
if (curl) {
    string st_url = "";
    const char *url= st_url.c_str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
    string st_postfields = "mystuff";
    const char *postfields= st_postfields.c_str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfields);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 7209);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "192.168.1.130:7209");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

i commented what i found online and tried with no results.

#### Situation 4 (NO SSL - actual)

I think the real problem is in the modified coniìfiguration of the server API so i rolled back without ssl_module and my httpd.conf file is:

```
Listen 7209
ServerName 127.0.0.1:7209
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

The results didn't change from situation 3 to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically after all that the problem was pretty simple: the 3rd party hosting my website was blocking the requests on non standard ports. I simply asked(and waited 2 days) the technical assistance. For everybody knowledge Aruba supports outgoing requests only on:

- FTP 21
- HTTP 80
- HTTPS 443
- POP3 110, 995
- SMTP 465, 587
- IMAP 143, 993